# Gatsby - Error: Cannot find module '..\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\babel-loader.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby

When running `gatsby develop`, right after `gatsby new` with configurations provided in the tutorial here -  https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-1/, I am getting this error

> Module build failed (from ../../my-first-gatsby-sitenode_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):
> Error: Cannot find module '..\my-first-gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\babel-loader.js'

Solutions I have tried:

1. Delete node_modules, package-lock => npm install / yarn.
2. Run `npm install` in `node_modules/gatsby`.
3. npm -g --save babel-loader.

Please help if you have come across the error and been able to resolve it. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

> Run `npm install` in `node_modules/gatsby`.

`npm install` must be run in the root of your project, not inside `node_modules`.

> Delete node_modules, package-lock => npm install / yarn.

You should only choose npm or yarn, not both.

Try the following:

- Run the following: `npm install --save gatsby-cli`
- If you have many audit warnings before the previous command, run: `npm audit fix` (in the root of your project).
- Remove your `node_modules` and reinstall the dependencies in the root of your project by: `npm install`

Comment: I tried this but the problem still persists